# PostgresQL: Finding records that do not exist in query

Tags: sql, postgresql

Below, I have a query for a rankings table of players in a leaderboard.

Player information (including `pseudonym`) is stored in the `player` table, while rankings for each "matchday" (identified by `edition_id`) are stored in `players_rankings` as the competition is lineal (there's no points system, so rankings can't be computed mathematically). Information for each fixture is stored in `set` (`sw` denotes set wins, while `sl` denotes set losses).

```sql
SELECT
  players_rankings.rank, players_rankings.change, player.pseudonym,
  SUM(tot.sw) AS sw,
  SUM(tot.sl) AS sl
FROM players_rankings, player, (
    SELECT
      player1_id AS player_id,
      CASE
        WHEN score1 > score2 THEN 1 ELSE 0
      END AS sw,
      CASE
        WHEN score1 < score2 THEN 1 ELSE 0
      END AS sl
    FROM set WHERE edition_id = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
      player2_id,
      CASE
        WHEN score1 < score2 THEN 1 ELSE 0
      END,
      CASE
        WHEN score1 > score2 THEN 1 ELSE 0
      END
    FROM set WHERE edition_id = 1
  ) AS tot
WHERE
  players_rankings.edition_id = 1 AND
  tot.player_id = players_rankings.player_id AND
  players_rankings.player_id = player.id
GROUP BY 1, 2, 3
UNION
SELECT players_rankings.rank, players_rankings.change, player.pseudonym, 0, 0
FROM players_rankings, player
WHERE
  players_rankings.edition_id = 1 AND
  players_rankings.player_id = player.id
ORDER BY 1;
```

Which produces the following result:

```
-----+--------+---------------+----+----+
rank | change | pseudonym     | sw | sl |
-----+--------+---------------+----+----+
1    | 0      | Player One    | 1  | 0  |
-----+--------+---------------+----+----+
1    | 0      | Player One    | 0  | 0  |
-----+--------+---------------+----+----+
2    | 0      | Player Two    | 0  | 0  |
-----+--------+---------------+----+----+
3    | 2      | Player Three  | 1  | 0  |
-----+--------+---------------+----+----+
3    | 2      | Player Three  | 0  | 0  |
-----+--------+---------------+----+----+
4    | -1     | Player Four   | 0  | 1  |
-----+--------+---------------+----+----+
4    | -1     | Player Four   | 0  | 0  |
-----+--------+---------------+----+----+
5    | -1     | Player Five   | 1  | 0  |
-----+--------+---------------+----+----+
5    | -1     | Player Five   | 0  | 0  |
-----+--------+---------------+----+----+
6    | 3      | Player Six    | 0  | 0  |
-----+--------+---------------+----+----+
6    | 3      | Player Six    | 1  | 0  |
-----+--------+---------------+----+----+
7    | -1     | Player Seven  | 0  | 0  |
-----+--------+---------------+----+----+
7    | -1     | Player Seven  | 0  | 1  |
-----+--------+---------------+----+----+
8    | -1     | Player Eight  | 0  | 0  |
-----+--------+---------------+----+----+
8    | -1     | Player Eight  | 0  | 1  |
-----+--------+---------------+----+----+
9    | -1     | Player Nine   | 0  | 0  |
-----+--------+---------------+----+----+
10   | 0      | Player Ten    | 0  | 1  |
-----+--------+---------------+----+----+
10   | 0      | Player Ten    | 0  | 0  |
-----+--------+---------------+----+----+
11   | 0      | Player Eleven | 0  | 0  |
-----+--------+---------------+----+----+
12   | 0      | Player Twelve | 0  | 0  |
-----+--------+---------------+----+----+
```

My goal with the query after the `UNION` was to get only registered players that didn't feature in the first "matchday" (`players_rankings.edition_id = 1`, i.e. players Two, Nine, Eleven, and Twelve), but I hit a brick wall trying different methods to achieve that, including different `JOIN`s. As such, I went back to the drawing board and used the aforementioned query to start again with the duplicate values as shown above. Below is the desired result:

```
-----+--------+---------------+----+----+
rank | change | pseudonym     | sw | sl |
-----+--------+---------------+----+----+
1    | 0      | Player One    | 1  | 0  |
-----+--------+---------------+----+----+
2    | 0      | Player Two    | 0  | 0  |
-----+--------+---------------+----+----+
3    | 2      | Player Three  | 1  | 0  |
-----+--------+---------------+----+----+
4    | -1     | Player Four   | 0  | 1  |
-----+--------+---------------+----+----+
5    | -1     | Player Five   | 1  | 0  |
-----+--------+---------------+----+----+
6    | 3      | Player Six    | 1  | 0  |
-----+--------+---------------+----+----+
7    | -1     | Player Seven  | 0  | 1  |
-----+--------+---------------+----+----+
8    | -1     | Player Eight  | 0  | 1  |
-----+--------+---------------+----+----+
9    | -1     | Player Nine   | 0  | 0  |
-----+--------+---------------+----+----+
10   | 0      | Player Ten    | 0  | 1  |
-----+--------+---------------+----+----+
11   | 0      | Player Eleven | 0  | 0  |
-----+--------+---------------+----+----+
12   | 0      | Player Twelve | 0  | 0  |
-----+--------+---------------+----+----+
```

How should I go about achieving this?

Comment: If you increase the number of suqueries by one level and use the condition sw = 1 or sl = 1, the desired output will be reached.

Comment: @MeysamAsadi I'll explore this further. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use window function `ROW_NUMBER()` and `partiton by rank` and sort with `case statement`.

Using the `Row_Number` function, group the rows that have the same rank, and then, based on the fact that the row has the condition `sw = 1 OR sl = 1`, the value of one is included in the sort, otherwise the value 0 is then sorted in descending order.

In fact, the `Row_Number` function numbers the rows based on the same rank, and in the main query, the rows that are numbered number one are fetched.

```
SELECT rank,change,pseudonym,sw,sl
FROM
  (SELECT *,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY rank ORDER BY CASE WHEN sw = 1 OR sl = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END DESC)   AS num
  FROM
    (SELECT
      players_rankings.rank, players_rankings.change, player.pseudonym,
      SUM(tot.sw) AS sw,
      SUM(tot.sl) AS sl
    FROM players_rankings, player, (
        SELECT
          player1_id AS player_id,
          CASE
            WHEN score1 > score2 THEN 1 ELSE 0
          END AS sw,
          CASE
            WHEN score1 < score2 THEN 1 ELSE 0
          END AS sl
        FROM set WHERE edition_id = 1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
          player2_id,
          CASE
            WHEN score1 < score2 THEN 1 ELSE 0
          END,
          CASE
            WHEN score1 > score2 THEN 1 ELSE 0
          END
        FROM set WHERE edition_id = 1
      ) AS tot
    WHERE
      players_rankings.edition_id = 1 AND
      tot.player_id = players_rankings.player_id AND
      players_rankings.player_id = player.id
    GROUP BY 1, 2, 3
    UNION
    SELECT players_rankings.rank, players_rankings.change, player.pseudonym, 0, 0
    FROM players_rankings, player
    WHERE
      players_rankings.edition_id = 1 AND
      players_rankings.player_id = player.id) T) T
WHERE num = 1      
ORDER BY 1;
```

*Demo in [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=6f12e5b5b895ada10b79c960b26cfdfd)*

Comment: This worked. Thanks! Could you explain what's happening with the functions step-by-step? (Aside from the queries I mentioned earlier that you've used in your answer, of course)

Comment: i edited answer . see this link https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=232ab1b5288325d41209d41ac6825190

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Had to play around with the code in bits to really grasp the concept but I've understood it now. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Caveat: I haven't finished my morning coffee yet... If I understand your question correctly the following (un-tested) approach could work:

```
WITH pr AS (
    SELECT players_rankings.player_id,
            players_rankings.rank,
            players_rankings.change,
            player.pseudonym
        FROM players_rankings
        JOIN player
            ON ( players_rankings.player_id = player.id )
        WHERE players_rankings.edition_id = 1
),
tot AS (
    SELECT t.player_id,
            sum ( t.sw ) AS sw,
            sum ( t.sl ) AS sl
        FROM (
            SELECT player1_id AS player_id,
                    CASE
                        WHEN score1 > score2 THEN 1
                        ELSE 0
                        END AS sw,
                    CASE
                        WHEN score1 < score2 THEN 1
                        ELSE 0
                        END AS sl
                FROM SET
                WHERE edition_id = 1
            UNION ALL
            SELECT player2_id,
                    CASE
                        WHEN score1 < score2 THEN 1
                        ELSE 0
                        END,
                    CASE
                        WHEN score1 > score2 THEN 1
                        ELSE 0
                        END
                FROM SET
                WHERE edition_id = 1
            ) AS t
        GROUP BY t.player_id
)
SELECT pr.rank,
        pr.change,
        pr.pseudonym,
        0 AS sw,
        0 AS sl
    FROM pr
    FULL OUTER JOIN tot
        ON ( pr.player_id = tot.player_id )
    WHERE tot.pseudonym IS NULL
    ORDER BY 1 ;
```

**edit** fix columns in full outer join